# Packaging Adobe Air for iOS: not supported on Darwin error

Tags: ios, flash, air, packaging

I'm trying to pack Adobe Air app to an iOS. The problem is that I **always** get this error:

```
unexpected failure: Functionality not supported on : Darwin
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Functionality not supported on : Darwin
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.<init>(AOTCompiler.java:220)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.GOAOTCompiler.<init>(GOAOTCompiler.java:55)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.createIosBinary(IPAOutputStream.java:447)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.finalizeSig(IPAOutputStream.java:860)
    at com.adobe.air.ApplicationPackager.createPackage(ApplicationPackager.java:91)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAPackager.createPackage(IPAPackager.java:273)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseArgsAndGo(ADT.java:591)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.run(ADT.java:435)
    at com.adobe.air.ADT.main(ADT.java:485)
```

Firstly, I faced this error while I'm tried to run it through emulator

```
adt -package -target ipa-test-interpreter-simulator -storetype pkcs12 -keystore cert.p12 -storepass password myApp.ipa hello-app.xml Main.swf -platformsdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
```

After that, I thought that maybe things get better when I pack it on iPhone with real certificates. Nope.

```
adt -package -target ipa-debug -keystore cert.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass password -provisioning-profile iOS_Team_Provisioning_Profile_.mobileprovision HelloWorld.ipa hello-app.xml  Main.swf Default.png
```

Same effect. So, according to stack trace and my experiments I think the problem appears while air compiling file from swf to ipa. What should I do?

Some additional info:

```
adt -version
13.0.0.76

java -version
openjdk version "1.7.0-b147"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147-20111031)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

hello-app.xml file contents:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0">
    <id>ru.hello.world</id>
    <versionNumber>1.0.1</versionNumber>
    <filename>Hello World</filename>
    <name>Example Co. AIR Hello World</name>
     <description>
        <text xml:lang="en">This is an example.</text>
        <text xml:lang="fr">C'est un exemple.</text>
        <text xml:lang="es">Esto es un ejemplo.</text>
    </description>
    <copyright>Copyright (c) 2010 Example Co.</copyright>
    <initialWindow>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <content>Main.swf</content>
    </initialWindow>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Java. I used open JDK, but when I downgrade it back to default mac JRE the problem solved.